# Order by IDs in SQL IN() with Rails using Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-geocoder

I'm issuing 2 queries, one that collects the IDs in the order I need them to be and they're passed into the 2nd query which gets the information, this is my first query:

```
Location.near([lat, lng], 1, units: :km).order("distance").map(&:id)
```

Each `Location` has an associated `Venue` which I query like so:

```
Venue.where("location_id IN (?)", location_ids)
```

I want the venues queried to have the same order their respective locations. For instance if location 1 is the first location has ID 5 and is associated to a venue with ID 10 I want that venue to be the first result in the 2nd query as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order the `venues` according after extracting the `location_ids`:

I assume that you have an association in venue `belongs_to :location`:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

so your code will be:

```
location_ids = Location.near([lat, lng], 1, units: :km).map(&:id)
Venue.joins(:location).where(locations: {id: location_ids }).order("locations.distance")
```